# Rename tag [typesafe-activator] to [lightbend-activator]

Tags: discussion

Typesafe [changed its name](http://www.lightbend.com/blog/whats-in-a-name) to Lightbend a while ago, so the tag for activator should be renamed also, because now it is [Lightbend Activator](https://www.lightbend.com/community/core-tools/activator-and-sbt).

Comment: We should rename it and then mark `[typesafe-activator]` as a synonym of `[lightbend-activator]`, to be sure it won't be used anymore.